# automation for checking mail login and password. But it always shows incorrectly when I give my own password

Tags: python, automation, gmail

I am trying to log in to mail using imaplib for confirmation but it gave me always incorrect. but if I used a less secure password it would work. But I want to use only the original password.

```
import imaplib

def check_email_login(email, password):
    try:
        imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
        imap.login(email, password)
        imap.logout()
        return "Success"
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
        return "Incorrect"
```

Comment: Which passwords work, and which don't?

Comment: Have you tried to check if your password is affected by escape characters `(\)` which may affect how imap.login is working?

Comment: I am trying my own mail and password.